# how to scrape all the pages on a real estate website using pyton?

Tags: python

I need some assistance scraping multiple pages for a real estate website. I have written the code to scrape page 1 successfully and attempted to implement code to **scrape** all 25 pages of it but am now stuck. Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer


base_url = 'https://www.rew.ca/properties/areas/kelowna-bc'
url = '/page/2'

while url:
    response = requests.get(f"{base_url}{url}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    listings = soup.find_all("article")

    with open("property4.csv", "w") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(["title", "type", "price", "location", "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "square feet", "link"])
    for listing in listings:
        location = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-info").get_text().strip()
        price = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-title hidden-xs").get_text().strip()
        link = listing.find("a").get('href').strip()
        title = listing.find("a").get('title').strip()
        type = (listing.find(class_="clearfix hidden-xs").find(class_="displaypanel-info")).get_text()
        bedrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[2]).get_text()
        bathrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[3]).get_text()
        square_feet = (listing.find_all("li")[4]).get_text()
        csv_writer.writerow([title, type, price, location, bedrooms, bathrooms, square_feet, link])
        next_btn = soup.find(class_="paginator-next_page paginator-control")
        url = next_btn.find("a")["href"] if "href" else None
```

Answer (score 0):

You should increment the page number every time that it scrapes a page. Try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

base_url = 'https://www.rew.ca/properties/areas/kelowna-bc'

for i in range(1, 26):
    url = '/page/' + str(i)

    while url:
        response = requests.get(f"{base_url}{url}")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        listings = soup.find_all("article")

        with open("property4.csv", "w") as csv_file:
            csv_writer = writer(csv_file)
            csv_writer.writerow(["title", "type", "price", "location", "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "square feet", "link"])
        for listing in listings:
            location = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-info").get_text().strip()
            price = listing.find(class_="displaypanel-title hidden-xs").get_text().strip()
            link = listing.find("a").get('href').strip()
            title = listing.find("a").get('title').strip()
            type = (listing.find(class_="clearfix hidden-xs").find(class_="displaypanel-info")).get_text()
            bedrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[2]).get_text()
            bathrooms = (listing.find_all("li")[3]).get_text()
            square_feet = (listing.find_all("li")[4]).get_text()
            csv_writer.writerow([title, type, price, location, bedrooms, bathrooms, square_feet, link])
            next_btn = soup.find(class_="paginator-next_page paginator-control")
            url = next_btn.find("a")["href"] if "href" else None
```

Comment: thanks for that, unfortunately it still seems to just extract the first pages results.

Comment: If you understand where I'm going with that, you could probably adapt your code to work with it

Comment: do you mind providing a little more clarification? I'm pretty new at all this and any extra information is greatly appreciated

Comment: Each page, 1-25 on that website, has a corresponding url. So the end of the third page's url would be /page/3 and the end of the 15th page's url would be /page/15. If you look at the code that I added at the top, it sets i to 1 and sets your url variable to /page/i, with i being the value of i. And every time your code under that runs, i will be increased by 1 until it hits i = 25. Hope that helps

Comment: Apologies for the dumb questions. I believe I understand the logic of what you're saying on this. Where I am mostly getting caught up is adapting the code. i.e when I implement you're for loop and print something such as 'title' it continuously loops over the same page and spits out the same 20 listings over and again.

Comment: Sorry, there's a lot of errors and I can't fix it right now. I might be able to fix it later but probably not. Sorry